# Disallow implicit accessing of window properties

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm looking for an ESLint rule that disallows usage like `location` and only allows `window.location`. I've combed through the rules, but didn't find one, does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [no-restricted-globals](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals) rule will help you with this.

Add this to your `.eslintrc` file

```
"no-restricted-globals" : [
    "error",
    "location",
    "history",
]
```

So in the above example eslint won't throw an error if you use `window.location` or `window.history`. You can add more window properties to the list.

Comment: Is there a rule to only restrict window's properties, instead of manually add all possible ones?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't, eslint library doesn't maintain the list of properties that exist on window object. So you'll have to maintain the list of properties yourself in the .eslintrc file.